# Generar ejecutable en c#

Tags: c#, .net

Estaba interesada en saber cómo se podría generar un ejecutable desde otro ejecutable.

Me explico, imaginemos que tengo un form dónde en unos textboxs se le piden, que sé yo, un email, asunto, mensaje etc...

Pero a mi no me interesa que al darle a un botón, se envie el mensaje, sino generar un ejecutable, y al ejecutar esa aplicación se envie un mensaje, ¿Cómo demonios se compila un ejecutable desde otro ejecutable?

Comment: mmm... y el codigo de ese nuevo ejecutable, quien lo escribiria?? cual es la motivacion para esto? tal vez podes explicar? porque suena raro lo que queres hacer... algo asi como un virus?

Comment: No está muy claro lo que preguntas. Si sería posible generar un ejecutable desde otro, pero no es algo sencillo. Tal vez si explicas mejor cual es la motivación para hacer eso podamos ayudarte mejor. Yo nunca he tenido que hacer algo similar para nada, asi que no se me ocurre en que sutiación eso sería necesario...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En runtime puedes generar codigo usando las librerias del `CodeDom`

[Compiling C# Code at Runtime](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime)

[How to programmatically compile code using C# compiler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304655/how-to-programmatically-compile-code-using-c-compiler)

algo como esto

```
string code = @"
    using System;

    namespace First
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
            " +
                "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello, world!\");"
                + @"
            }
        }
    }
";

CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
```

por supuesto el codigo esta simplificado, despues debes validar si hay errores en la compilacion y puede ejecutar lo que compilaste, pero creo que da uan idea

Comment: Muchas gracias otra vez por tu ayuda, Leandro! :)